# Online alternative of MS project

Tags: project-management

Is there an online (free) project management tool that we can generate start and due date automatically through :

- The first task in the project, with start and due dates set
- Dependencies between tasks
- Calendar of each team member, working hours per day, working days per week

I am able to do that with `MS project` and `omniPlan` on mac, but I can't find an online ( somehow free) tool with the exact features, I tried `Trello` & `Clickup` but you should set dates manually for each task

Thanks in advance!